# How i can Change my URL by .htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Here is my current URL

```
http://prdemos.com/Web/2015/wessexcars/internalpage.php?id=*any_numeric_value*
```

i want the URL like this

```
http://prdemos.com/Web/2015/wessexcars/wenchester
```

Comment: But `wenchester` is not there in rewritten URL and rewrite rules cannot convert `wenchester` to a numeric value.

Comment: @anubhava here is my situation, when i click on any internal page, by id, and there is an seo title of each page so now i want to show the seo of Pages in URL instead of page id

Comment: @anubhava here is my project URL 
http://prdemos.com/Web/2015/wessexcars/internalpage.php?id=4
and i want like this
http://prdemos.com/Web/2015/wessexcars/this-is-seo-of-page-by-id

Comment: As I said above rewrite rules cannot convert **seol title** to a numeric value by querying your database

Comment: ok thanks let me try by direct seo url not by numeric

Answer (score 0):

Only this one? And depends if you want user to see final url, or only that your code sees the final one? Try one of these:

```
RewriteRule ^Web/2015/wessexcars/internalpage.php?id=\d+$ Web/2015/wessexcars/internalpage [L,NC] 

RewriteRule ^Web/2015/wessexcars/internalpage.php?id=\d+$ Web/2015/wessexcars/internalpage [R=301,L,NC]
```